# /bin/node permission denied after setting CHMOD 777

Tags: php, node.js, permissions

this is for Amazon EC2 linux.

I have a PHP script that runs a shell script.

So inside the shell script is a command to run node.

When I run the PHP script from the command line, the node executes.

When I run the PHP script from the browser, I get this message in the apache log:

```
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node: Permission denied
```

This is after doing a chmod 777 on /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node

I also did chown ec2-user:apache /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node

Also, here is the result of:

```
$ ls -alrt /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node

-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user apache 34800111 Jun 12 22:40 /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node
```

Everyone has full permissions on it, how can I be getting a "Permission denied" error?

So again this works perfectly if I run the PHP script from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a total no-no but it's temporarily a hack.

Since this is running on my AWS EC2 instance, I simply restrict everything via the security group and only allow the I.P. addresses I allow, so it's safe for me.

You have to add the permissions to the apache group in the sudoers file.

So, first:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

And then add:

```
%apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

To the end of the file.  Again, it's bad, it's a hack, but it's a current workaround and I restrict access to the EC2 instance via the I.P. addresses in the security group anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this then you can go to `/etc/sudoers` and make apache as your sudo user and it will have root privileges to run the file in the browser.
The changes you will have to make are :- 
First find the line

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

and then add the line below it

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```